# Calculate matrix in cubic spline interpolation

Tags: math, geometry

I read the article on https://www.value-at-risk.net/cubic-spline-interpolation/

I understand all but I don't know how I can get the values for the matrix:

[image]

I know that there is something like hi = hi+1 - hi

I visited several websites, read different explenations, but I never found out how exactly I come to this values in the matrix.

Comment: I assume you want to know how they goes from [2.127] to [2.128], which mean: how to solve `M.X = V` , with M a square Matrix of dimension `n`, X and V are vectors of dimension `n`   ?

Comment: I want to know how they get the values for the matrix M.

Comment: then, you need to edit your question, and include more details, btw, I think, this question is more suited for http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I mentioned twice in my question, that I need to know how exactly I get the values for the matrix. Where is the problem?

Comment: there is no problem :) I'am trying to understand what you're looking for to give you a better answer. and because your question is unrelated to programming it's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. so, I suggested an other place, where you can find more answers.

Comment: @YounesAitLoutou I agree ... btw this has nothing to do with SPLINEs euther it is just simple cubic polynomial fit

Comment: @Spektre indeed, I just can't write all the mathematics symbol quickly to explain [Representing linear systems with matrix equations](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/precalc-matrices/solving-equations-with-inverse-matrices/v/matrix-equations-systems). and I think this what the OP is looking for. considering that he "understand all but ..."

Comment: @zer0kai added few things to answer (you accepted quicker then I finish editing :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix is just system of equations encoded as matrix so it can be easily computed by inverse matrix.

For example second line of matrix `(8,4,2,1,0,0,0,0)` after matrix multiplication means this:

```
a3.2^3+a2.1^2+a1.2^1+a0=5
```

which is your `p1(2)=5` the lines are:

```
p1(1)=1
p1(2)=5
p2(2)=5
p2(3)=4
p1'(2)-p2'(2)=0
p1''(2)-p2''(2)=0
p1''(1)=0
p2''(3)=0
```

so for example last matrix line `( 0,0,0,0,18,2,0,0 )` is this:

```
b3.18 + b2.2 = 0
```

If we derive `p2(t)` up to 2-nd derivation

```
p2(t) = b3.t^3 + b2.t^2 + b1.t + b0
p2'(t) = 3.b3.t^2 + 2.b2.t + b1
p2''(t) = 2.3.b3.t + 1.2.b2  = 6.b3.t + 2.b2
```

Now for `t=3` we get:

```
p2''(3) = 6.b3.3 + 2.b2 = 18.b3 + 2.b2
```

And encoded into matrix (last line)

```
(0,0,0,0,18,2,0,0) * ( a3,a2,a1,a0,b3,b2,b1,b0) = 0
```

Which matches your example. Hope it is clear now ...

Beware this example of yours is just for `y` axis as you got 2D curve you need to do this for `x` axis in the same manner again ...

Now let rewrite the matrix equation again:

```
M*A=B
```

Where `M` is your `8x8` matrix, `A=(a3,a2,a1,a0,b3,b2,b1,b0)` and `B=(1,5,5,4,0,0,0,0)` you can solve this like this:

```
inverse(M)*M*A = inverse(M)*B
             A = inverse(M)*B
```

So you obtain the `A` which holds your `p1,p2` polynomials coefficients for `B` which holds your position (`y` coordinates in one pass and x coordinates in the next) so you got `p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y` polynomials. Which is what you need for the interpolation.

However this approach is a bit backward and usually predefined polynomial forms are used like SPLINE,BEZIER with defined properties like continuity, linearity, etc (no need for inverse matrix operation). But if you need custom properties like in this example then you do not have much of a choice.

For more info see [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)

Comment: good explanation, but what I like most is the use of code format instead of what I was going for ^^"