# Is it possible to Interpolate without loop

Tags: excel, vba, interpolation, linear-interpolation, cubic-spline

I was wondering if it was possible to interpolate **without using loop** in order to earn processing  time.

---

**Note :** Interpolation goal is to calculate point which does not exist on my curve. For Example the rate for 9 october 2021

---

Curve Example

[image]

---

Actually I am using a For loop in order to browse my curve to calculate the point. Does a Smartest way exist ?

```
Function DCF(Periode As Double) As Double
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 21
    Date1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Courbes").Range("PeriodeCourbe").Offset(x).Value
    Date2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Courbes").Range("PeriodeCourbe").Offset(x + 1).Value
    TauxMid1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Courbes").Range("Mid").Offset(x).Value
    tauxMid2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Courbes").Range("Mid").Offset(x + 1).Value
    If Periode >= Date1 And Periode < Date2 Then DCF = 1 / (Date2 - Date1) * ((Periode - Date1) * tauxMid2 + (Date2 - Periode) * TauxMid1)
Next
End Function
```

> I am using spline cubic interpolation but a simple example with linear
> interpolation will help me to build my own function.

Comment: Look at this good example https://mathformeremortals.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/cubic-and-bicubic-interpolation-excel-functions/.

Comment: @pizzettix but in your example he still use loop, i was wondering if an other way without loop was existing

Comment: simple linear you can use the worksheet formulas SLOPE and INTERCEPT to create a linear formula that will do what you want.

Comment: @Dorian: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920162/calculate-matrix-in-cubic-spline-interpolation. Maybe you can express the solution as a matrix multiplication (it depends on the cubic interpolation type)? In excel and vba you can caluculate with matrix too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it more efficiently without a loop using approximate MATCH/VLOOKUP.

see my post here for code and a comparison of the 2 methods.

https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-2/