# How would I implement root-finding when all I have is a set of points?

Tags: swift, math, swift3, bisection

I have some code that outputs two arrays that contain x-values and y-values. I now need to root-find using these points, but is this possible without knowing the function? How does one implement, say, the bisection method using ***only*** a set of `(x, y)` pairs (no function `f(x)`)? All of the examples that I'm finding online show the bisection method being used with a predefined polynomial function. Do I *need* to first find an approximate function in order to use the bisection method?

Comment: You could fit a curve to the points and get roots from that.  What do roots mean here?  All you need to do is look for consecutive points with alternating signs for the y-component, then do a linear interpolation to figure out the x where y = 0 between them.  You're doing too much searching and not enough thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by root you mean point with `y=0.0`

find 2 consequent points `(x0,y0),(x1,y1)` such that `y0*y1<=0.0` that means they are crossing zero so root is somewhere between them so take `n` points around this place and form polynomial (interpolation or BEZIER or whatever) and then use bisection or any other method.

For starters you can use linear interpolation so just solve this:

```
x(t) = x0 + (x1-x0).t // parametric line x
y(t) = y0 + (y1-y0).t // parametric line y
y(t) = 0.0 // root y
x(t) = ?   // root x
---------------------
0.0 = y0 + (y1-y0).t
t = -y0/(y1-y0)
---------------------
x(t) = x0 + (x1-x0).t 
x(t) = x0 + -y0/((y1-y0).(x1-x0)) // this is your approximate root
```

You may want to look at:

- [How approximation search works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36163846/2521214)
- [How can I produce multi point interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)

Also handle special cases when `y0` or `y1` are zero. That means they are the root and you do not need to interpolate. If they are both zero then you got infinite number of roots in-between them