# Cubic spline interpolation drops out halfway

Tags: matplotlib, interpolation, astronomy, cubic-spline

I am trying to make a cubic spline interpolation and for some reason, the interpolation drops off in the middle of it. It's very mysterious and I can't find any mention of similar occurrences anywhere online.

This is for my dissertation so I have excluded some labels etc. to keep it obscure intentionally, but all the relevant code is as follows. For context, this is an astronomy related plot.

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

W = np.array([0.435,0.606,0.814,1.05,1.25,1.40,1.60])
sum_all = np.array([sum435,sum606,sum814,sum105,sum125,sum140,sum160])
sum_can = np.array([sumc435,sumc606,sumc814,sumc105,sumc125,sumc140,sumc160])

fall = CubicSpline(W,sum_all)
newallx=np.arange(0.435,1.6,0.001)
newally=fall(newallx)

fcan = CubicSpline(W,sum_can)
newcanx=np.arange(0.435,1.6,0.001)
newcany=fcan(newcanx)

#----plot

plt.plot(newallx,newally)
plt.plot(newcanx,newcany)
plt.plot(W,sum_all,marker='o',color='r',linestyle='')
plt.plot(W,sum_can,marker='o',color='b',linestyle='')
plt.yscale("log")
plt.ylabel("Flux S$_v$ [erg s$^-$$^1$ cm$^-$$^2$ Hz$^-$$^1$]")
plt.xlabel("Wavelength [n$\lambda$]")
plt.show()
```

The plot that I get from that comes out like this, with a clear gap in the interpolation:

[image: img]

And in case you are wondering, these are the values in the sum_all and sum_can arrays (I assume it doesn't matter, but just in case you want the numbers to plot it yourself):

```
sum_all:
[  3.87282732e+32   8.79993191e+32   1.74866333e+33   1.59946687e+33
   9.08556547e+33   6.70458731e+33   9.84832359e+33]
can_all:
[  2.98381061e+28   1.26194810e+28   3.30328780e+28   2.90254609e+29
   3.65117723e+29   3.46256846e+29   3.64483736e+29]
```

The gap happens between [0.606,1.26194810e+28] and [0.814,3.30328780e+28]. If I change the intervals from 0.001 to something higher, it's obvious that the plot doesn't actually break off but merely dips below 0 on the y-axis (but the plot is continuous). So why does it do that? Surely that's not a correct interpolation? Just looking with our eyes, that's clearly not a well-interpolated connection between those two points.

Any tips or comments would be extremely appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I do not understand the pgm language but I assume you use single cubic SPLINE which has 4 control points and `t^3` as highest order polynomial part so that limits it up to 2 bumps and 1 inflex point. your dataset has more of each so either use higher order SPLINE (but that tends to oscillate too)  or use [piecewise interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214).

Comment: @Spektre `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline` does perform a **piecewise** spline interpolatation.  This means that the number of splines is one less than number of points to interpolate. You can therefore have 1 point of inflection per pair of points.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest looks like you got it (+1) I did not spot the log scale ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the breakdown can be better observed on a linear scale.

[image]

We see that the spline actually passes below 0, which is undefined on a log scale.

So I would suggest to first take the logarithm of the data, perform the spline interpolation on the logarithmically scaled data, and then scale back by the 10th power.

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

W = np.array([0.435,0.606,0.814,1.05,1.25,1.40,1.60])
sum_all = np.array([  3.87282732e+32,   8.79993191e+32,   1.74866333e+33,   1.59946687e+33,
   9.08556547e+33,   6.70458731e+33,   9.84832359e+33])
sum_can = np.array([  2.98381061e+28,   1.26194810e+28,   3.30328780e+28,   2.90254609e+29,
   3.65117723e+29,   3.46256846e+29,   3.64483736e+29])

fall = CubicSpline(W,np.log10(sum_all))
newallx=np.arange(0.435,1.6,0.001)
newally=fall(newallx)

fcan = CubicSpline(W,np.log10(sum_can))
newcanx=np.arange(0.435,1.6,0.01)
newcany=fcan(newcanx)


plt.plot(newallx,10**newally)
plt.plot(newcanx,10**newcany)
plt.plot(W,sum_all,marker='o',color='r',linestyle='')
plt.plot(W,sum_can,marker='o',color='b',linestyle='')
plt.yscale("log")

plt.ylabel("Flux S$_v$ [erg s$^-$$^1$ cm$^-$$^2$ Hz$^-$$^1$]")
plt.xlabel("Wavelength [n$\lambda$]")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That seemed to solve it entirely. I will remember my logs in the future. Really grateful!