# Create a plot graphs with c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The Y axis will be scaled automatically, depending on the values coming fallowing function.

```
void mouseHandleCordinate(double val){
  // include graph function.
}
```

So I want to create the plot chart against the time. X axis represent time and Y represent the value coming above function. How I create above graph function.

Always pass the data into `void mouseHandleCordinate(double val)` function.
As example:

```
val >>> 2.1,3,1,6,7,5.5,0,9,5,6,7,3.6,2,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4 >> represent double val
Time>>> 21,20,19,18,17,......., 4,3,2,1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure I got what you asking but looks like you want to create continuous function following table of sampled points like:

```cpp
const int N=21; // number of samples
const double t0=21.0,t1=1.0; // start,end times
const double val[N]={ 2.1,3,1,6,7,5.5,0,9,5,6,7,3.6,2,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4 };

double f(double t) // nearest
 {
 t = (t-t0)/(t1-t0); // time scaled to <0,1>
 t*= (N-1); // time scaled to <0,N) .. index in table
 int ix=t; // convert to closest index in val[]
 if ((ix<0)||(ix>=N)) return 0.0; // handle undefined times
 return val[ix]; // return closest point in val[]
 }
```

This will give you the nearest neighbor style function value. If you need something better use linear or cubic or better interpolation for example:

```cpp
double f(double t) // linear
 {
 t = (t-t0)/(t1-t0); // time scaled to <0,1>
 t*= (N-1); // time scaled to <0,N) .. index in table
 int ix=t; // convert to closest index in val[]
 if ((ix<0)||(ix>=N)) return 0.0; // handle undefined times
 if (ix==N-1) return val[ix]; // return closest point in val[] if on edge
 // linear interpolation
 t = t-floor(t); // distance of time between ix and ix+1 points scaled to <0,1>
 return val[ix]+(val[ix+1]-val[ix])*t; // return linear interpolated value
 }
```

Now to your problem:

```
void mouseHandleCordinate(double mx) // mouse x coordinate in [pixels] I assume
 {
 double t,x,y,x0,y0

 // plot
 x=0;
 y=f(view_start_time)
 for (t=view_start_time;t<=view_end_time;t+=(view_end_time-view_start_time)/view_size_in_pixels,x0=x,x++)
  {
  y0=y; y=f(t); 
  // render line x0,y0,x,y
  }

 // mouse highlight
 t = view_start_time+((view_end_time-view_start_time)*mx/view_size_in_pixels);
 x = mx;
 y = f(t);
 // render point x,y ... for example with circle r = 16 pixels
 }
```

where:
 
 `view_start_time` is time of the left most pixel in your plot view
 
 `view_end_time` is time of the right most pixel in your plot view
 
 `view_size_in_pixels` is the x resolution in [pixels] of your plot view

**[Notes]**

I code the stuff directly in SO editor so there may be typos ...
Hoping you are calling the `mouseHandleCordinate` in some Paint event instead of on mouse movement which should only schedule repaint order... Also you should add y view scale in similar manner to x scale I used ...

For more info see:

- [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)