# How do I connect four 2D grid points with a smooth curve in C# and give the x and y location back at a certain time?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, game-engine, bezier

So I'm trying to connect four grid points with x and y values together with a smooth curve. **Given a parameter 'time'** I want to receive the **x and y locations** of the point on the curve **at that time.**

I've tried multiple options like quadratic bezier curves and such but can't seem to figure it out.

There's no need to visualize it in Unity, wpf or any other way.  I don't need a draw method or anything like that. **I simply need the position value of the point in the curve.**

This is the sort of curve I am looking for:

[image: Example]

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Comment: see [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214) what you want is piecewise interpolation cubic (or catmull-rom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach is using [Catmull-Rom splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline).
 [Example of implementation](https://qroph.github.io/2018/07/30/smooth-paths-using-catmull-rom-splines.html)

[Some more variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Interpolating_a_data_set)

Note that parameter t varies from 0 to 1 at every point-point interval, so you can map your "position" onto corresponding interval. For example, if position varies from 0 to 1, mutliply it by 3. Integer part of result is interval number, fractional part - parameter t at this interval.