# 3D Polynomial Interpolation

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, interpolation, curve

I am trying to create a 3D wireframe by interpolating known points on generated cross-sections. I need a smooth polynomial interpolating function for the collection of points with known XYZ coordinates that need to be interpolated. I will then need to evaluate this function to obtain the rest of the XYZ-coordinates in between. I have used cubic spline interpolation in the past for 2D applications but I haven't found anything useful for 3D applications.

I have looked into Tricubic interpolation but my points are not strictly increasing in the y and z coordinates and I don't have any known function that describes them. Finally I have looked into a reliable Catmull-Rom spline library.

Is there any interpolation method or library that can help me create smooth 3D curves given these x[], y[],z[] arrays. PS. My solution ideally needs to in java.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: cubics are the same in any dimensionality ... you use the same equations for each axis separatelly. so what is the problem?

Comment: @Spektre My objective is to use a single method to interpolate the points in 3D not to combine 2 or 3 2D interpolations. Can you please clarify what you mean cubics are the same in any dimensionality? Will I get a smooth 3d surface by interpolating each axis separatelly?

Comment: point on any polynomial parametric cubic curve in any dimensionality is computed `p(t)=a0 + a1*t + a2*t*t + a3*t*t*t` where t is scalar parameter usually in range t=<0.0,1.0> , a0..a3 are vector polynomial coefficients and p(t) is vector position for used t The way how you compute the a0..a3 defines what kind of curve it is (for example using Bernstein polynomials or nesting linear interpolation give you BEZIER) but the equation is the same for all coordinates for more info see sublinks in [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)